# app.component in angular 2 is mandatory to be staring component?

Tags: visual-studio, angular, angular2-routing

Currently I am using Visual studio for angular application with online Angular 2 template. The application is working fine when I choose default template and app.component as starting component. but when i need to change it with another component as starting component(home.component) my application not working.

Please guide me.

Comment: please provide the code in which you change it to home.component

Comment: I think its not, have you updated component name in `app.module.ts` bootstrap array?

Answer (score 1):

This is what you app module will be like now

```
  @NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent // change this to HomeComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent] // change this to HomeComponent
})
```

If you want to change the AppComponent to a different component just change the `bootstrap` array and `declarations` array to HomeComponent.

And if you you want to route use the `RouterModule` in importsto route from app to home component.